# Server and domain conflict

Tags: networking, dns, website

I have a question about what happens/how to solve a conflict, assume the following:

- Person A has full access to a server at IP adres X.
- Person B holds the rights for domain name P.
- A DNS entry has been made that domain P points to IP adres X, only person A can remove that setting.

Now a conflict might arise between person A and B.
Person B wants to buy their own server Y and ensure that domain name P links to IP adres Y.

How to go about such a situation? Can two DNS entries be there at the same time? What are the rules in case there would be two DNS entries.

As far as I know the domain and server are 'contracted' by totally different companies.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, whoever bought the domain name first, have the right to redirect the domain name to their IP/server. So if Person B manages to secure domain P by certain domain registrar, Person A is pretty stuffed, unless Person A can re-purchase that domain name. But this is only the technical point of view. There are some legal method (which I can't find the reference for it) where if you can claim that Person B are domain squatting, then you may force (by law) the domain registrar to release that domain to Person A. Can someone correct me here..?

Comment: I might've made it too complicated, can the owner of the domein name change the DNS settings? If so, then I think everything is ok. I'm just a bit confused, because the only reference I have is my own hosting/name, which are both tied to me and same customer number, so their relevant options are intertangled.

Comment: To my knowledge, yes the owner of the domain can point the domain to any IP of their choosing. The new information from the domain registrar will propagate the new Domain->IP information to all other connected DNS server accordingly so after a while, the new domain->IP information will be correct (pointing to the new IP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entity that registered the domain name has control over the DNS namespace. If Person B registered the domain name then Person B has control of the DNS namespace and can point the domain to where ever they want. Person A would have no access to or control of the DNS namespace unless Person B gave them that access and control.